# erro em conversão de my_sql para PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Modifiquei minha pagina de conexão com o banco de dados de MYSQL para PDO mas ele esta apresentando erro, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Tem um arquivo que puxa as informações necessárias do banco de dados para ser enviada para o index da meu site e apresentar os 5 últimos comentários presentes no Banco de Dados.
Ele gera o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\fraturaexposta.esy.es\home.php on line 87
```

que no caso seria na linha do codigo a baixo

```
  <div id="comenthome">" <?=$result['comentario']?> "<br>- <?=$result['user_name']?> .</div>
```

esse é o arquivo que faz a conexao com o banco de dados

```
<?php

define( 'MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'MYSQL_USER', 'root' );
define( 'MYSQL_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'MYSQL_DB_NAME', 'test' );

try
{
    $PDO = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . MYSQL_HOST . ';dbname=' . MYSQL_DB_NAME, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD );
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
    echo 'Erro ao conectar com o MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT user_name, comentario FROM comentario ORDER BY coment_id desc limit 5";
$result = $PDO->query( $sql );
$rows = $result->fetchAll();


?>
```

esse é o php que puxa os comentarios do banco de dados para a pagina

```
<?php

    // se o número de resultados for maior que zero, mostra os dados

    if($rows > 0) {

        // inicia o loop que vai mostrar todos os dados

        do {

?>



<hr>

<div id="comenthome">" <?=$result['comentario']?> "<br>- <?=$result['user_name']?> .</div>



<?php

        // finaliza o loop que vai mostrar os dados

    }while ($rows = $PDO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

    // fim do if 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rows = $result->fetchAll();` Já retorna um array, então basta fazer um foreach com `$rows`.

O problema é o seu `do-while` que sobrescreve toda hora `$rows`

```
}while ($rows = $PDO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Para corrigir faça:

```
<?php 
   // ...demais linhas
   $rows = $result->fetchAll();
?>

<?php foreach($rows as $result){?>
<hr>
<div id="comenthome">" <?=$result['comentario']?> "<br>- <?=$result['user_name']?>.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: no caso eu teria que colocar o foreach na pagina do site ou do que conecta com o banco de dados?

Comment: a ta entendi agora ele subistitui o `do-while`

Comment: @FraturaExposta na página do site.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui

Comment: ♦ vc poderia dar uma olhada nesse meu outro problema de PDO? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163788/erro-em-contador-de-visitas-com-php-pdo-e-mysql